# Generics in Java -- implementing interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface with prototype

```
public interface genericInterface <E extends Comparable <E>>{}
```

and now I want to implement this inerface in my class, what I should wirte in class definition? The following line is giving me an error (I have implemented all the methods in the interface)

```
public class MyClass<Integer> implements genericInterface**<Integer Comparable<Integer>>**{ }
```

Syntax...

```
genericInterface<Integer Comparable<Integer>> -- error

genericInterface<Integer> -- error
```

what I should write in place of `<Integer Comparable<Integer>>` to make it compatible?

Comment: You can't use generics pre java 1.5.

Comment: I am using java 1.7...

Comment: You should change your Java 1.4 tag then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class declaration should just be:

```
class MyClass implements genericInterface<Integer>
```

Generic parameters after the class name are for parameters of that class, not of classes that it is implementing.

So, for example:

```
interface genericInterface<E extends Comparable <E>> {
    E getKey();
}
class MyClass<T> implements genericInterface<Integer> {
    T getValue();
}

MyClass<String> m = new MyClass<String>();
Integer a = m.getKey(); // Because MyClass always has E = Integer
String b = m.getValue(); // Because m has T = String

genericInterface<Integer> g = new MyClass<Boolean>();
Integer c = g.getKey();
```

You can also do:

```
class MyClass<E extends Comparable <E>> implements genericInterface<E>
```

Then you can have instances of `MyClass` parameterized with any type that would work for `genericInterface`.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot but then if I have a method in the interface 
`method(Myclass<E> arg1)` would give me an error right?
saying that myclass is not generic , it should be parametrized with `<E>`

Answer (score 0):

Generics are available in Java only since version 1.5. You should use raw types.

Comment: He said he is using java 1.7.So there should be no reason why he should not be using powerful features of geenrics

Comment: I left answer before he left comment about 1.7. Also, previously question had tag java 1.4